# Zend Framework SEO tips

Tags: zend-framework, seo

I've done basic work suggested by Google and others to improve Google ranking. What are the 'specific' things I should do with Zend Framework (or in general any MVC architecture) to make it better? It seems all the usual methods aren't working that well with Zend Framework.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing special to ZF or any other MVC framework. The only ZF-specific thing I can think of is that in ZF you can use the router and routes to create those nice looking URLs that people claim to be SEO friendly. Also, you can use the headMeta helper to create metatags but that's basically all...

There is no magic trick to it.

Comment: @Jani: All the files (application, models, views) are below web root directoty. Does that make any difference?

Comment: No, because those files should never be accessed directly anyway.

Comment: Nope.  Other than it's a good practice.

Answer (score 2):

With Zend_Navigation you can also easily create XML Sitemaps which can help to index your website.